# How do I fetch all results from a filtered query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from itertools import groupby
from flask import request
import MySQLdb
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from db import PUser


engine = create_engine('mysql://myusername:mypassword@localhost/mydbname')
engine.connect()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://myusername:mypassword@localhost/mydbname'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


@app.route('/people/')
def people():
    result = pUser.query.filter_by(shahr = 'tehran')
    result = PUser.query.all()

    return result
```

In the script above, how should I edit these lines to work?

```
result = PUser.query.filter_by(shahr = 'tehran')
result = PUser.query.all()
```

I want to select all data from "PUser" table and also know how to filter my select query.

`Puser` is the name of a table in my database, and this is a part of db.py in the same directory:

```
class PUser(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'p_user'
```

Comment: You could indent your file properly for a start, then explain what you're trying to do and what the problem is.

Comment: can you show your full table...what is shahr?

Comment: `shahr = Column(String(collation='utf8_bin'), nullable=False)` "shahr" means "city" in my language.

Answer (score 3):

You are making two queries and that's probably why you aren't getting the desired result.

`pUser.query` creates a [`Query`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query) object. On that you're able to call stuff like `select_from`, `join`, `filter`, `filter_by` and other methods like that, which also return a `Query` object.

To get the resulting rows to a python `list`, you have to call `all`, `one` etc. on that.

So, in your case

`result = pUser.query.filter_by(shahr='tehran').all()`

Comment: I tried but this error raised: `AttributeError: type object 'PUser' has no attribute 'query'`

Comment: I believe it should be: `session.query(pUser).filter_by(shahr='tehran').all()`

Comment: `Model.query` is a feature of flask-sqlalchemy.  If you are using SQLAlchemy directly, the correct syntax is `session.query(Model)`.